# Googke K8s - Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring is enabled but cant see logs in Logs Viewer

Tags: logging, google-stackdriver

Google K8S - Master version **1.13.6-gke.6**

On my K8S cluster is Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring Enabled, Legacy Stackdriver Logging   Disabled, Legacy Stackdriver Monitoring Disabled.

PROBLEM: I get monitoring information in stackdriver dashboards but I **cant see logs in google Logs Viewer** (also nothing with gcloud logging read "resource.type=k8s_container" to this cluster)

If I switch to Legacy Stackdriver Monitoring and Legacy Stackdriver Logging, it works (with resource.type=container).

Cluster use service with permission (Role editor (owner not help))

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring

Permissions for cluster

- Stackdriver Logging API  - Write Only
- Stackdriver Monitoring API - Full

On every node runing fluentd-gcp-*

Comment: Have you reviewed that you have stackdriver logging enabled? (not the legacy one). On the other hand, I would like to share this document with you [1] [1] https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/migration